# Reading Sharepoint List Calculated field from PowerShell

Tags: list, sharepoint

I am trying to pull data from a SharePoint list. The field is a calculated column that takes a yes or no answer and changes the words to archived and non-archived. 
I can see the data being formatted correctly in the calculated column in IE but when I try to pull the data it shows up as nothing when I check the variable data.

```
$site = get-spsite https://extranet./sites/site
$web = get-spweb -Identity https://extranet/sites/site
$list=$web.getlist("https://extranet/sites/site/lists/List");
$View = $list.Views["LISTVIEW"]
$listitems = $list.Getitems($view) 

foreach ($listitem in $listitems) {
```

I have tried this also but get an indexing a null variable error.

```
$mailboxdb = $listitem.Fields["mailboxdb"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCalculated];            
$mailboxdb.GetFieldValueAsText($listitem["mailboxdb"]);
```

I see this also in the $listitems output. ows_MailboxDb='string;#Archived'

But when I check $mailboxdb its empty.

Found this but I don't know what it means by stored results.

In Powershell, although you can reference any field in the list in your script, you can only compare  retrieve values from "static" fields - that is, you cannot use calculation fields. PowerShell will not complain - but you will not get results in your script. This is because the .Net library for Sharepoint will not do the field calculation for you - that only happens inside the Sharepoint UI itself.

If you need to have access to a "calculated" field, you actually need to have two fields - the calculated field (usually hidden) and a "stored result" field, which must be updated from the calculated value in the last step of the "Update" workflow. Then you can use the "stored value" field in PowerShell - and also, incidentally, in View calculations in Sharepoint.

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> $mailboxdb = $listitem.GetFormattedValue("mailboxdb")
Exception calling "GetFormattedValue" with "1" argument(s): "Column 'mailboxdb' does not exist. It may have been 
deleted by another user."
At line:1 char:1
+ $mailboxdb = $listitem.GetFormattedValue("mailboxdb")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two options here.  You can have Powershell do the calculation for you, which is probably the simpler of the two options given the basic nature of your calculation.

The second option, as mentioned at the end of your post is to create a new field which can store the result of the calculation.  In your case, you could call it status.  Then you would create a workflow that runs whenever a list item is updated or created that stores the results of the calculated field in the results field.  This seems redundant to me if you have this field for no other reason than to use the value of the calculated field in a PowerShell script.

Comment: Thanks for the powershell calculation idea. I just made that variable an if else command.